# How to delete the first character of a byte array, and save it to a file

Tags: c#, winforms

Im working on a simple form app that can conceal images. basically the program should take an image, convert it to a byte array, add a character to the front of the byte array and output the image with a .jpg extension. This makes the image appear corrupted.

Ive completed the first half and the program is outputting the image with the added character. I just need help deleting the character.

So like the first half you should be able to open a file dialog select the "concealed" image, and delete the first byte that is making it appear corrupted.

Im looking to open the concealed file, convert it to a byte array, delete the first character of that byte array, and output it as a file.

```
namespace ArrayEditor
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(ofd.FileName);
                string[] TBBites = textBox2.Text.Split(',');

                int i = 0;
                foreach (byte bite in bytes)
                {
                    if (i == Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text))
                    {
                        for (int x = 0; x < TBBites.Count(); x++)
                        {
                            bytes[i + x] = Convert.ToByte(Convert.ToInt32(TBBites[x]));
                        }
                        break;
                    }

                    i++;
                }

                File.WriteAllBytes("F://V2 Dog (Encrypted).jpg", bytes);
            }


        }
                    //textBox3
        private void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

                    //textBox4
        private void TextBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
            if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(ofd.FileName);



                File.WriteAllBytes("F://V2 Dog.jpg", bytes);
            }
        }
    }
```

Expected results:

Concealment:
1. User opens an image with the first button.
2. Program outputs to file with an added byte at the front of the byte[] and a .jpg extension.

De-Concealment:
1. User opens a concealed file with file dialog.
2. Program outputs file without the added byte at the front of the byte [] and a .jpg extension.

Comment: Does this work? `File.WriteAllBytes("F://V2 Dog.jpg", bytes.Skip(1));`

Comment: you maybe better off using BlockCopy. here is a good summary with sample code. https://www.dotnetperls.com/buffer

Comment: @ConradFrix It shouldn't; `File.WriteAllBytes` requires `Byte[]` as arg, not `IEnumerable<Byte>`. You'd have to add `.ToArray()`, and in Linq, the generics involved in these actions make the operation a lot slower than a simple manual array copy.

Answer (score 2):

A modern approach, but depends on the version of .net you are targeting, would be to use a Span and the Slice method.

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(originalFilePath);
var span = bytes.AsSpan();
var slice = span.Slice(1);
var result = slice.ToArray();
```

if span is not available in the version you are targeting then something like block copy, or one of the many other more perf friendly answers.

```
var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(originalFilePath);
var result = new byte[bytes.Length-1];
Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 1, result, 0, bytes.Length-1);
```

Comment: "AsSpan" is getting an error /:

Comment: what version of .net are you targeting?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why you'd read the file byte by byte since you are not doing any operations on byte level. You are doing a file level operation. You only want to prepend a byte to the data and later remove (de-prepend) that byte.

Something like this should work:
To conceal ("prepend"):

```
var originalData = File.ReadAllBytes(originalFilePath);
var newData = new byte[originalData .Length + 1];
newData[0] = 0; // Or whatever you want the prepended data to be.
Array.Copy(originalData, 0, newData, 1, originalData.Length);
```

To reveal ("de-prepend", "de-conceal"):

```
var concealedData = File.ReadAllBytes(concealedFilePath);
var originalData = concealedData.Skip(1).ToArray();
```

*Disclaimer: Code not tested.*